# How do you configure a NetApp Filer to use LDAP for username/password/uid?

Tags: samba, ldap, netapp

We have a NetApp Filer, and want to access it via Samba/CIFS, and have it use the username/password/uid available in our OpenLDAP server. We already do this successfully with Samba 3 against OpenLDAP, so we have all the appropriate posix attributes as well as NT/LanManager password attributes.

The goal is that a user can mount their directory in Windows with the same username/password as their Linux login, and files created there will have the correct uid so it just works when they go back to Linux.

Again, we have all this working with Samba/OpenLDAP/Linux, so the question is not about that configuration. It's about configuring a NetApp against such a system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

options ldap.base dc=example,dc=com
options ldap.servers ldap.example.com
options ldap.enable on
edit nsswitch.conf

Edit /etc/nsswitch.conf

hosts: files dns
passwd: ldap files 
netgroup: ldap files 
group: ldap files 
shadow: files nis

This [now link requires a valid login](http://now.netapp.com/NOW/knowledge/docs/ontap/rel7311_vs/html/ontap/filesag/accessing/task/t_oc_accs_configuring_LDAP_services.html)

As always its worth testing things on the simulator first :)

Comment: If you have any issues then edit the question.